# How to setup sound intensity on windows mobile?

Tags: c++, windows, windows-mobile

I playing a sound file with a custom player, when the mobile goes in suspend mode (because the user pushed the red button) I would like to resume sound intensity when the mobile resume. How can I do ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set the volume by opening the waveOut device and setting the volume.  This will affect all sound playback:

waveOutOpen

waveOutSetVolume